# ¿Cómo mostrar un registro a partir de su ID utilizando la clase Query Builder de CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy creando un CRUD y no consigo hacer que los registros con determinado ID aparezcan en el input de mi formulário:

1. Tengo el siguiente **Model**:

a) Con esta función consigo el id del registro

```
public function showGameId($id)
    {
        return $this->db->table($this->table)->getWhere('id',$id )->getRowArray();
    }
```

b) Con esta otra función intento ya hacer el update del registro:

```
public function updateGameDB( $id, $game )
    {
    return $this->db->table( $this->table )->where( 'id', $id )->update( $game );
    }
```

- Entonces obtengo la pagina Ejemplo: misitio/editar/2; hasta ahí todo bien.

2. **Controllers**: Mi función donde muestro el formulário

   ```
    public function editGame($id = null)
    {
    helper('form');
    $gamesModel = new GamesModel();


    $data = [
        'title' => 'Edit Game',
        // id for link editgame/#id
        'game'  => $gamesModel->showGameId($id),

        // Data for Form Helper inputs
        'dataInputName' => [
            'name' => 'name',
            'id' => 'name',
            'placeholder' => 'Your Name',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'type' => 'text'
        ],
        'dataInputDeveloper' => [
            'name' => 'developer',
            'id' => 'developer',
            'placeholder' => 'Developer',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'type' => 'text'
        ],
        'dataInputPrice' => [
            'name' => 'price',
            'id' => 'price',
            'placeholder' => 'Price',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'type' => 'text'
        ],
        'submitButton' => [
            'name'=>'submit',
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
            'type' => 'submit',
            'value' => true,
            'content' => 'Submit'
        ]
    ];
    return view('Pages/editGame', $data);
    }
   ```
3. Mi **View** del formulario donde estoy intentando recuperar el registro especifico:

   ```
    if ( isset( $game ) ):
    ?>

    <?= form_open('Games/updateGame')?>
    <?php
    else:
    ?>
    <?= form_open('Games/newGame')?>

    <?= csrf_field()?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= form_label('Name', 'name')?>
        <?= form_input($dataInputName, $game['name']  )?>
    <?= "<strong style='color: red'>".$validation->showError('name')."</strong>" ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= form_label('Developer', 'developer')?>
        <?= form_input($dataInputDeveloper,$game['developer']   )?>
    <?= "<strong style='color: red'>".$validation->showError('developer')."</strong>" 
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= form_label('Price', 'price')?>
        <?= form_input($dataInputPrice, $game['price']   )?>
    <?= "<strong style='color: red'>".$validation->showError('price')."</strong>" ?>
    </div>

    <?= form_button($submitButton)?>

    <?= form_close()?>

    <?php
    endif;
    ?>
   ```

Mi pregunta seria: ¿Cómo consigo obtener un registro en cada input de mi formulario utilizando también Query Builder?

Answer (score 0):

No acabo de entender muy bien que intentas lograr 
Entiendo que lo que quieres es conseguir mostrar todos los registros en la base de datos que estén relacionados con el id que tu le pasas

Si te fijas en tu modelo lo que haces es buscar una row( fila) que cumpla la condición, si quieres todos los registros que cumplan esa condición deberías usar getResult() o getResultArray() si lo quieres trabajar como un array

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Aquí tienes la documentación respectiva